# LAB: Interstate highway numbers

Tags: python

I have a assignment to write a program that takes a highway number as input and outputs whether the highway is primary or auxiliary, goes east/west, north/south, and if it is auxiliary, what primary highway is it serving. Here is my code:

```
highway_number = int(input(''))

if highway_number >= 1 and highway_number <= 99:
    prim = 'is primary,'
    if (highway_number % 2) == 0:
        print('I-', highway_number, prim, 'going east/west.')
    else:
        print('I-', highway_number, prim, 'going north/south.')
elif highway_number >= 100 and highway_number <= 999:
    aux = 'is auxiliary,'
    if (highway_number % 2) == 0:
        print('I-', highway_number, aux, 'serving I- %d, going east/west.' % (highway_number%100))
    else:
        print('I-', highway_number, aux, 'serving I- %d, going north/south.' % (highway_number%100))
else:
    print(highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
```

But if I run it. It adds a space between the "I-" and the highway number. [image: Screenshot]

Comment: [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the part where you print: Using `print(string, string)` your writing out 2 seperate stings, which per default by python will be seperated by a blank space. Your going to have to append the strings which can easily be done by a + `print(string + string)`. BE sure to parse numbers etc first using `str(toparse)`.

For the second part printing a space between I- and the number its because in your string you have a space `I- %d`. Yust change it to `I-%d`

Hope this helps :D

In complete

```
highway_number = int(input(''))

if highway_number >= 1 and highway_number <= 99:
    prim = 'is primary,'
    if (highway_number % 2) == 0:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), prim, 'going east/west.')
    else:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), prim, 'going north/south.')
elif highway_number >= 100 and highway_number <= 999:
    aux = 'is auxiliary,'
    if (highway_number % 2) == 0:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), aux, 'serving I-%d, going east/west.' % (highway_number%100))
    else:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), aux, 'serving I-%d, going north/south.' % (highway_number%100))
else:
    print(highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just used a combination of the above answers and a little bit of my own coding. If you're in C859 and following Zybooks, chances are you haven't learned about %d yet (at least I don't remember seeing this yet). We did, however, learn about string formatting, so I wanted to figure out a way to print 'I-90,' without a space after the comma in the second block of code. Also, I added an else statement that provides an error-free result in submit mode of zybooks.

```
#LAB 5.15 Interstate Highway Numbers
#Odd numbers go north/south
#Even numbers go east/west

highway_number = int(input())
prim = 'is primary,'
aux = 'is auxiliary,'
serv = highway_number % 100

if highway_number >= 1 and highway_number <=99:
    if highway_number % 2 == 0:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), prim, 'going east/west.')
    else:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), prim, 'going north/south.')
elif highway_number >= 100 and highway_number <= 999:
    if highway_number % 100 == 0:
        print(highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
    elif highway_number % 2 == 0:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), aux, 'serving I-{}, going east/west.'.format(serv))
    else:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), aux, 'serving I-{}, going north/south.'.format(serv))
else:
    highway_number <= 0 and highway_number >= 1000
    print(highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
```

Comment: You may want to look into reformatting your code using f-strings, since that is considered best practice now.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`print('I-'+str(highway_number), prim, 'going east/west.')`

and

`print('I-'+ str(highway_number), aux, 'serving I-%d, going east/west.' % (highway_number%100))`

Answer (score 0):

The question to this answer has changed by adding new requirements added new section to help others out that are looking for the same answers.

```
highway_number = int(input())

if highway_number >= 1 and highway_number <= 99:
    prim = "is primary,"
    if (highway_number % 2) == 0:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), prim, 'going east/west.')
    else:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), prim, 'going north/south.')
elif highway_number >= 100 and highway_number <= 999:
    aux = 'is auxiliary,'
    if highway_number % 100 == 0:
        print(highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
    elif (highway_number % 2) == 0:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), aux, 'serving I-%d, going east/west.' % (highway_number%100))
    else:
        print('I-' + str(highway_number), aux, 'serving I-%d, going north/south.' % (highway_number%100))
else:
    print(highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32721729)

Answer (score 0):

```
highway_number = int(input())
service_highway = highway_number % 100

if highway_number >= 1 and highway_number <= 99:
    highway_type = 'primary'            
    if highway_number % 2 == 0:
        highway_direction = 'east/west'
    else:
        highway_direction = 'north/south'
    print(f'I-{highway_number} is {highway_type}, going {highway_direction}.')

elif highway_number >= 100 and highway_number <= 999:
    highway_type = 'auxiliary'
    if highway_number % 100 == 0:
        print(f'{highway_number} is not a valid interstate highway number.')
        
    elif highway_number % 2 == 0:
        highway_direction = 'east/west'
    else:
        highway_direction = 'north/south'
    print(f'I-{highway_number} is {highway_type}, serving I-{service_highway}, 
          going {highway_direction}.')
    
else: 
    print(f'{highway_number} is not a valid interstate highway number.')
```

Comment: Total noob at Python, but figured it out without cheating or getting help. Found this towards the end when I couldn't get it to run properly but decided to keep what I had done. My issue was with indentations and not with the code itself. I'm sure there's a better/more efficient way to write this but maybe this can help another total noob in the future understand each step in a way that other more advanced answers did not.

Answer (score 0):

You want to see a minimalist solution?

```
import math
highway_number = int(input())
exclude = [0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900]

if highway_number <= 99 and not (highway_number in exclude):
    remain = math.fmod(highway_number, 2)
    direction = 'north/south.' if remain == 1 else 'east/west.'
    print(f"I-{highway_number} is primary, going {direction}")

elif (highway_number < 1000) and not (highway_number in exclude):
    math_highway = math.fmod(highway_number, 100)
    remain = math.fmod(math_highway, 2)
    direction = 'north/south.' if remain == 1 else 'east/west.'
    main_highway = int(math_highway)
    print('I-{0} is auxiliary, serving I-{1}, going {2}'.format(highway_number, main_highway, direction))
    
else:
    print (highway_number, 'is not a valid interstate highway number.')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. In particular, please explain why this is a "minimalist solution" relative to the other answers. Thanks